# Есть ли возможность экстренно узнавать что в БД PostgreSQL появилась запись?

Tags: django, postgresql, mqtt, iot

Есть система которая, которая имеет django-бэкенд, некий фронтэнд, базу данных Postgres и плагин, который сохраяет некие сообщения в БД от mqtt-брокера.

Так вот, от брокера (плагина) в базе данных сохраняются сообщения не только статистики от датчиков, но и сообщения об ошибках, которые имеют критический характер. Возможно ли из БД отправлять сигнал, что появилась запись в базе данных с критическим характером? Или каким то другим образом отлавливать данные сообщения? Задача такая, чтобы пробросить эти сообщения до фронтэнда и при отключеном клиенте от web-портала отсылать ему почту или смс (здесь не так важен функционал).

Т.е. спрашивать периодически базу о таких сообщениях конечно можно, но система достаточно большая и включает в себя порядка 20к датчиков.

UPD: в комментариях было предложено использовать NOTIFY/LISTEN. Есть ли другие решения или технологии?

Comment: [Notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-notify.html) + WebSocket

Comment: @AntonShchyrov спасибо, за направление. Прочитал и понял, что мне нужно повесить два бесконечных цикла: один NOTIFY, второй LISTEN  с указанием канала. Насколько это будет дорого для БД? Хотя мысль о том, что это функционал Postgres, дает надежду, что это лучшее решение

Comment: Я не работал с Postgres и не знаю деталей реализации, но в других СУБД клиентское подключение с LISTEN просто блокируется пока не придет событие из БД или получает асинхронное уведомление. а NOTIFY вызывается в триггере или хранимой процедуре после модификации данных. Так что никаких бесконечных циклов нет

Comment: Похоже что для LISTEN таки [нужен](https://habr.com/ru/company/tensor/blog/484978/) бесконечный цикл

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то нужна гарантированная доставка. А LISTEN - не транзакционный и сообщения могут теряться. Чтоб сделать надежную доставку уведомлений без потерь, слушателя нужно усложнить (ему придется хранить информацию о том, какие уведомления он уже получил, а перед подпиской проверять нет ли пропущенных). Из того, что вы описали, то лучше всего использовать mqtt, а не пытаться из БД это добыть. Например, создать отдельный топик и в него писать перед тем, как пишете в БД. Ну и отдельный подписчик на этот топик будет рассылать уведомления уже пользователям.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я рассматривал такой вариант, но сталкиваюсь с тем, что если пользователи не используют в данный момент времени mqtt-клиент, то он получит уведомление об ошибке только в момент подключения. Я плавно прихожу к тому, что нужно писать отдельный обработчик для таких сообщений, вешать клиента и проч... Ой, как не хочется=(

Comment: Я не вполне понимаю ваши ожидания. Если пользователь прямо сейчас не слушает, то кто ж еще может послать ему сообщение если не отдельный, специально предназначенный обработчик, который запущен всегда на сервере? Тут не принципиальной разницы с точки зрения общего подхода. Будет ли он выполнять LISTEN или слушать mqtt топик и получив уведомление отсылать смс, почту или еще что.

Comment: Возможно будет полезно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215600/postgres-is-there-a-way-of-executing-code-following-a-insert-statement/25218653#25218653 и https://bit.ly/3ue98UN

Comment: @RomanKonoval спасибо. Я думал, что я что-то упускаю и не вижу решения. Мои ожидания, чтобы ничего не делать и все работало=) А, если серьезно, то я надеюсь, что кто-то уже собирал такое и может опытом поделиться. Хочется лаконичного и доступного в поддержке решения.

Comment: какой допустимый срок реакции оповещения на  критические сообщения? мнгновенный? 30 секунд? минута? ...

Comment: @Manul74 нет какого то строго заданного значения, т. е. и бороться за милисекунды тоже не надо в данной задаче. "Критические" сообщения в данном контексте означают, что требуется вмесшательство или внимание оператора. Короче, "ничего не горит, но что то происходит"

Comment: @Дмитрий  ну тогда если по простому опрашивать некую таблицу раз в 5 - 10 секунд 1 минута, в которую скидываются/дублироваться только нужные критические сообщения, на которые требуется реакция. По мере их считывания удалять. Считал сообщение удалил. Послал сигнал бедствия по смс....  Соответственно таблица будет практически пустая и особой загрузки не будет. Это самый простой путь не городить что то сложное. Не знаю есть ли в Postgres сервер agent как в mssql сервере на который можно поставить задачу переодического опроса базы. У меня такие вещи работали нормально. Сервер не грузили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое от чего стоит отталкиваться это то, что БД ни при каких обстоятельствах не может сама инициировать подключение. Всё общение с БД происходит по принципу: один запрос пользователя - один ответ от БД. Соответственно никакой сигнал или что-то ещё она вам отправлять не будет ни при каких обстоятельствах. Это говорит о том, что дальше будет 2 пути развития:

1. Самый тупой и лёгкий. Периодическая задача, которая скажем, выполняется раз в минуту и проверяет не появилось ли в БД чего нового. Это приводит к тому, что появляется лишняя нагрузка на БД и мы тратим лишние ресурсы. Так же это происходит не моментально.
2. Самое правильное решение. О том, что появилась новая запись мы должны узнать не от БД, а от того, кто её вставил. Ваш плагин должен отправить вам "сигнал" о том, что он вставил новую запись. Готового решения нет, оно индивидуально под каждый проект и пишется самостоятельно.

Я описал лишь доставку сообщения от БД (или того кто вставляет в БД) до бэка. Доставка сообщений от бэка до фронтенда осуществляется с помощью websocket. Django один из худших вариантов для websocket, как и все другие синхронные решения. Посмотрите на асинхронные фреймворки (например fastapi, вряд ли вы найдёте что-то лучше в питоне)

Comment: django вполне себе [поддерживает](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) асинхронную обработку. Поддержка websocket-ов в джанго базируется на ней, поэтому агрумент `как и все другие синхронные решения` не понятен.

Comment: @RomanKonoval django не умеет в асинхронную работу с БД. Любой запрос к базе блочит экземпляр приложения, этим всё сказано

Comment: @RomanKonoval так же попрошу заметить что django channels это ни разу ни классическая питонячья асинхронность. Это лишь попытка имитировать её. Производительность таких решений очень слабая и ресурсозатратная. Я не говорил что это невозможно сделать в django, я сказал, что это плохой вариант

Comment: @Inventor я соглашусь с тобой насчет channels. Да, это имитация, но время ставит задачи и перед разработчиками django. С 3-ей версии появляются возможности для [асинхронного функционала](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/)

Comment: @Дмитрий вот специально для таких жертв маркетинга как ты залез в код django и посмотрел как django обрабатывает "асинхронные корутины". Знаешь чё они делают? Берут твою корутину и применяют к ней `async_to_sync` делая из твоей корутины обычную синхронную функцию и выполняют её синхронно вне `event loop`.

Comment: @Inventor ух, холивар хэс бэган=) я знаю, что там под капотом и я не заявлял категорично, что django умеет в асинхрон. Просто товарищи знают свои косяки и придумывают решения, улучшают и проч.

Comment: @Дмитрий то что они сделали это никакое ни решение. использование async перед функцией ничем не отличается от обычной функции. Выполняется всё точно так же как при синхронных функциях, никакой разницы. Чисто маркетинг, чтобы сказать, смотрите, мы асинхронность сделали, хотя они сделали чисто возможность приписать `async` к функции при этом ничего не менняя

Comment: @Inventor вы, вероятно, что-то неправильно поняли или недоразобрались. django умеет из async обработчиков вызывать sync (и да - ORM все еще синхронный), и для этого есть адаптеры и вы вероятно на это наткнулись, когда смотрели код. При использовании asgi и только асинхронных middleware и вьюх, все будет работать асинхронно, как и должно. Так что последней комментарий, что джанго вообще не умеет asynс, и что разработчики всех ловко обманули - это явный перегиб.

Comment: @RomanKonoval вот именно что смотрел asgi обработчик, гляньте сами

Comment: Я написал свой комментарий проверив код, так как очень удивился такому заявлению, так как оно вообще не соответсвует моему опыту использования django с asgi. Может подскажите, в каком именно месте все асинхронное заворачивается в синхронное?

Answer (score 1):

Эммм..., а что нельзя создать триггер в Postgres, который вызывает процедуру, типа:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_insert_row();
```

Ну а далее рученьками написать хранимку (`on_insert_row()`), благо у Postgres богато с этим.

Люди аж [СМСки шлют - пример](https://gnuhost.medium.com/stored-procedures-as-rest-api-p-3-send-sms-from-the-function-28be26b19b15)

Comment: А как эта процедура должна сообщить что-то бэку?

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение приведу вариант с брокером (На примере Apache Kafka), можно настроить коннекторы для чтения определенной таблицы.
Не работал с MQTT, но судя по документации там тоже есть [коннекторы](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/config/odbc/#section-polling) ODBC.

Если в кратце:

1. вы подключаете коннектор на чтение на определенную таблицу(да хоть на много таблиц) и указываете в какие топики(да-да, можно писать сразу в несколько топиков) отправлять данные + прочие настройки.
2. На стороне бека отдельной задачей в селери/отдельным потоком/отдельным микросервисом/и тд и тп что больше нравится, подписываетесь на нужные топики, и при получении сообщения выполняете необходимые действия.

Comment: Интересно, как эти коннекторы обойдутся без периодических, частых запросов в БД (то что автор вопроса хочет избежать)?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Вы правы, не акцентировал внимание на этом)